# Flappybird game using Unity errors from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-engine, flappy-bird-clone

I want the sprite to make an impulse everytime I click the left button mouse but I'm getting errors from the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Aviao : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Rigidbody2D fisics;

    private void Awake()
    {
        this.fisics = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update () 
    { 
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            this.Impulsionar();
        }
    }
}

private void Impulsionar()
{
        this.fisica.AddForce(Vector2.up * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

> Assets\Script\Aviao.cs(21,5): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

> Assets\Script\Aviao.cs(21,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item

Comment: if you formatted your code you would see why.. the error is correct

Comment: `Impulsionar` is outside the class.

Comment: I formatted you code ... use a proper IDE and hit the auto-formatting ... now it should be clear what the issue is

Comment: Fix the formatting, move the `Impulsionar()` method inside the `Aviao` class and also fix the typo in that method: `this.fisics.AddForce()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you get is because your function `Impulsionar()` is out of your class and it is recognised as a modifier and not as a function.

Replace your code with the one below, it should fix the errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Aviao : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Rigidbody2D fisics;

    private void Awake()
    {
        this.fisics = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update () 
    { 
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            this.Impulsionar();
        }
    }

    private void Impulsionar()
    {
        this.fisica.AddForce(Vector2.up * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think a "modifier" is? Although your answer is (partially) correct, the explanation is not. The error CS0106 says that the `private` keyword is not an allowed modifier, which is the case because the method is indeed declared outside of the class.

Comment: In C# you can't declare any kind of functions outside of a class, struct, or interface, and they can't be declared as private, public, protected, internal, or protected internal if they're not in a class or struct.

Comment: The "modifier" that the error talks about is the keywords "private, public, protected, internal, and protected internal" which are used to define the accessibility of a type and its members. However, not all modifiers are allowed in all contexts.